# Resolve dependency with parameter

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-injection, ninject

Let's say I have the following classes:

```
class A
{
    // reference to B
    private B _b;

    // constructor for A
    public A(B b)
    {
        _b = b;
    }
}

class B
{
    private A _a;

    // constructor for B
    public B()
    {
        // initialize A and give it a reference on self
        a = new A(this);
    }
}
```

How do I replace manual initialization of A, with dependency injection, considering A implements corresponding interface IA, and I have the corresponding  binding in my ninject configuration:

```
.Bind<IA>().To<A>().InTransientScope();
```

Any workaround is welcome:)
P.S. It is a WPF application.

Comment: Bind IB to B before Binding IA to A. It should resolve automatically - It depends what IOC you use.

Comment: And Edit constructor of A, to  public A(IB b) instead of B

Comment: You should break the cyclic dependency by extracting shared logic out of either B or A into a new class C. You inject C into both A and B.

Comment: Class A is a receiver in the Command pattern and all it's methods are commands used by B and affect it's properties. If I remove reference to B, I will have to pass it as a parameter to each command.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to refactor your code to

```
class A {
  private B _b;
  public A(B b) {
    _b = b;
  }
}
class B {
  private A _a;
  public B(A a) {
    _a = a;
  }
}
```

However, this creates a circular reference and your container will probably throw an exception for this.

To work around this issue you need to refactor your code to

```
class A {
  private C _c;
  public A(C c) {
    _c = c;
  }
}
class B {
  private A _a;
  private C _c;
  public B(A a, C c) {
    _a = a;
    _c = c;
  }
}
class C {
  public C() {
  }
}
```

See [Circular Dependency in constructors and Dependency Injection](http://misko.hevery.com/2008/08/01/circular-dependency-in-constructors-and-dependency-injection/) on how to refactor your classes to C